# Продажа реальных товаров в Android-приложение

Tags: android

Как я могу сделать оплату запчастей или материалов в своем приложении?
Я так понимаю, что при оплате мне надо открывать внутри WebView какую-то страницу оплаты, где пользователь вводит номер своей карты Visa? 
Или подключением стороннего сервиса http://www.payonline.ru/
В общем какие правильные способы реализации есть?

Comment: Прдключаете платежку к своему приложению, после оплаты получаете callback (себе на сервер), делаете вещи.